# Merge AMR audio file in java or android

Tags: java, android, audio, audio-recording

I want record audio with pause an resume option in android.
for it I should record multiple file and merge them into single file.
But now how can I merge .amr file?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(This answer assumes we're talking about raw .amr files, not AMR data in a 3GP container or something like that)</sub>

The first 6 bytes of the file is an AMR signature, and the remainder of the file consists of audio frames. So you should be able to concatenate two AMR files by taking the full contents of the first file, and then append the contents of the second file *minus its first 6 bytes*.