# merge two amr files in android

Tags: android, merge, amr

im trying to merge two amr file in android
according this answer:
[Merge AMR audio file in java or android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069274/merge-amr-audio-file-in-java-or-android)
i deny first 6 byte from second file and then write into first amr file...
the output file is merging two file but it has noise right on connection second.
this is my code :

```
soundFile.createNewFile();                  
                FileInputStream inputStream1 = new FileInputStream(soundFile.getAbsolutePath()+0);
                FileInputStream inputStream2 =  new FileInputStream(soundFile.getAbsolutePath()+1);

                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(soundFile.getAbsolutePath()+"w"));

                int temp = 0;
                inputStream2.read();
                inputStream2.read();
                inputStream2.read();
                inputStream2.read();
                inputStream2.read();
                inputStream2.read();

                while( (temp = inputStream2.read()) != -1 )
                {
                    outputStream.write(temp);
                }

                outputStream.close();
                inputStream2.close();
                inputStream2 = new FileInputStream(soundFile.getAbsolutePath()+"w");

                SequenceInputStream inputStream3 = new SequenceInputStream(inputStream1, inputStream2);
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(soundFile);
                //FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(soundFile, true);
                while( (temp = inputStream3.read()) != -1 )
                {
                    outputStream.write(temp);
                }
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream1.close();
                inputStream2.close();
                inputStream3.close();
                //fileWriter.close();
                //fileWriter.flush();


            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
```

this is my first amr file:
http://www.filedropper.com/aaaa_2

this is second amr file: www.filedropper.com/aaaa_3

and this is my merge amr file: www.filedropper.com/aaaa_4

any1 can help me?

thx and sry for my english...

Answer (score -1):

You need to record files separately and then can join them together.

Use RAW AMR format. i.e. set recorder settings to:

```
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Once you have audio files generated in RAW AMR, you can join these files by striping the first 6 byes of file you are appending. Open the audio files in binary mode for the same.